# Nested classes: Accessing the methods of the outer class from the inner one

Tags: python, nested, nested-forms

Suppose you have two classes, `A` and `B`. Class B is defined inside the class A. I want to access the variables and methods of the outer class while inside the inner class. The code here is a toy example but has the essentials of what I want to demonstrate:

```
class A:
  a = 'even'
  b = 'odd'
  class B:
    def __init__(self, n):
      if n%2 == 0: self.num = a
      if n%2 == 1: self.num = b
      self.description = A.desc()

  def __getitem__(self, i):
    return self.B(i)

  def desc(self):
    return a + '-' + b

>>> c = A()
>>> d = c[4]
>>> TypeError: unbound method desc() must be called with A instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Here the method `desc` does some work on the variables of the class `A` and produces output. Class `A` is initialized correctly and you can access the variables `a` and `b`, even from the inner scope, given that you don't define the `description` variable. However, I cannot find a way to call the outer scope class methods `desc`. Is it possible to use the method `desc` in `B` without instantiating class `A`?

**Explanation on why I use such a pattern:**
Variables `a` and `b` in my program are rather big. I only need to initialize them once. In addition, I don't want these variables to float around in the program but to be only accessible to the inner class. Adding to all these is the fact that I can use the `A.__getitem__` to extract 'slices' of the big data when needed. So the outer class provides me with hiding/encapsulation of the data, the indexing operator (through `__getitem__`) and all the routines required for extraction of slices of data (here the method `desc`. The inner class, `B`, provides the bundling of useful information from the big data for each index. This, most likely, is not the optimal design for achieving the described task. I am open and eager to hear your opinion regarding the alternative patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see any reason for you to be using classes here, let alone nested ones. In any case, there is almost never a reason to nest classes in Python, since inner classes don't get any special access to the outer class.

However if you want to allow anything to access a method without instantiating the object, you can make it a classmethod:

```
@classmethod
def desc(self):
  return a + '-' + b
```

But I can't see why you would do any of this. Also, nothing here is a closure.

Comment: I accept this answer as `@classmethod` solves my problem to a large extent. I changed the the term 'closure' to 'nested'. I did a quick search and indeed this is not an example of a closure, so thank you! I added the explanation on to why I use this nested pattern.